# Running Spotify or Discord causes Ubuntu 17.10 to log me out

Tags: 17.10, session, wayland

I am new to Linux.

Running Spotify or Discord causes Ubuntu 17.10 to log me out. Maybe it is because of Wayland?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried those apps in 17.10, but you can switch back to the old Xorg server at the login screen by clicking the gear icon next to the sign in button:

https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/